# Validation error using `create()` in Mongoose transaction

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, transactions

I'm testing transactions using mongoose and trying to accomplish a very simple task with the following code:

```
      const session = await mongoose.startSession();
      session.startTransaction();
      try {
        const opts = { session, new: true };
        const A = await Author.
        create({
          firstName: 'Jon',
          lastName: 'Snow'}, session);
        if(!A) throw new Error('Aborted A by Amit!');
        const B = await Author.
        findOneAndUpdate({firstName: 'Bill'}, {firstName: 'William'}, opts);
        if(!B) throw new Error('Aborted B by Amit!');
        await session.commitTransaction();
        session.endSession();
      } catch (err) {
        await session.abortTransaction();
        session.endSession();
        throw err;
      }
```

All I'm trying to do is first insert (using mongoose `create()` method) a new document into a collection and then edit (using Mongo `findOneAndUpdate()` method) another document in the same collection. Failure of either query needs to abort the entire transaction suite.

It's the `create()` that seems to be giving me problems. The document does get created and inserted, however, it also throws an error:

> "Author validation failed: lastName: Path `lastName` is required.,
>   firstName: Path `firstName` is required."

Any idea what this could mean? It seems it's complaining about not being given values for `required` fields (`firstName` and `lastName`) despite me having already given it those.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have no idea why it would complain about missing values when I've provided them both and they're still getting added to the collection!

This is because [Model.create()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) first parameters accept documents to insert, as an array OR as a spread. For example, these two are equivalent:

```
// pass a spread of docs
Candy.create({ type: 'jelly bean' }, { type: 'snickers' }) 

// pass an array of docs 
Candy.create([{ type: 'jelly bean' }, { type: 'snickers' }])
```

The problem with your line, is that it's trying to take the second document `{session: session}` as another entry for `Author`, which is missing the required `firstName` and `lastName` fields.

Instead you should do:

```
Author.create([{ firstName: 'Quentin', lastName: 'Tarantino' }], 
               { session: session }
);
```

You may also find [Transactions in Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html) a helpful reference.

Comment: Thanks for the very insightful response, Wan. Care to take a look at this question if it's not too much trouble for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54881039/whats-the-most-economical-alternative-to-multiple-positional-identifiers-in-mon