# What's the most economical alternative to multiple positional identifiers in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection named **authors** with the following schema:

```
authors: {
  _id,
  firstName,
  lastName,
  posts: [
    post 1: {...},
    post 2: {...},
    post 3: {
      _id,
      title,
      content,
      tags: [
        tag 1: {...},
        tag 2: {...},
        tag 3: {
          _id,
          name,
          description,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

As can be seen, **posts** is an array of objects inside the **authors** collection. Each object inside this array, in turn, has **tags**, another array of objects. And each of these tags objects has three fields: **_id**, **name**, and **description**.

I'm trying to write a GraphQL mutation to update this **name** field on matching documents in the collection.

```
    const updatedTagInAuthor = await Author
  .updateMany({ 'posts.tags._id': args.newTagInfo._id },
    {
      $set: {
        'posts.$.tags.$.name': args.newTagInfo.name,
        'posts.$.tags.$.description': args.newTagInfo.description,
      },
    }, opts);
```

The above snippet obviously fails since MongoDB doesn't allow multiple positional elements (**$**) in a query. So is there any economical alternative to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

I tried the **ArrayFilter** method as MongoDB suggests:

```
           const updatedTagInAuthor = await Author.update(
              {},
              { $set: { 'posts.$[].tags.$[tag].name': args.newTagInfo.name } },
              { arrayFilters: [{ 'tag._id': args.newTagInfo._id }], multi: true }
            );
```

But this throws the following error:

> Cannot read property 'castForQuery' of undefined

Still confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the documents I'm updating with the kind of query I have given,

```
{"name" : "Steve","details" : [ {
        "work" : [ {
                "Company" : "Byjus",
                "id" : 1,
                "country" : "India"
            }, 
            {
                "Company" : "Vodafone",
                "id" : 2,
                "country" : "UK"
            }]
    }]},{"name" : "Virat","details" : [ {
        "work" : [ {
                "Company" : "Byjus",
                "id" : 1,
                "country" : "India"
            }, 
            {
                "Company" : "Verizon",
                "id" : 3,
                "country" : "US"
            }]
    }]}

QUERY:

db.getCollection('Users').update({"details": {"$elemMatch": {"work.id": 1}}}, {'$set': {'details.$[].work.$.Company': 'Boeing', 'details.$[].work.$.country': 'US'} }, {multi: true});
```

It's similar to what you asked right? 
Try inserting those two Documents in a collection called User and try the above query in Mongo CONSOLE directly, not in GUI. Use the Query completely not just the $set method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Author.update({"posts": { "$elemMatch": { "tags.id": args.newTagInfo._id } }}, 
    {'$set': {'posts.$[].tags.$.name': args.newTagInfo.name, 'posts.$[].tags.$.description': args.newTagInfo.description} }, 
    {multi: true});
```

Comment: Doesn't update anything but doesn't throw any error either.

Comment: I have updated the $elemMatch with { "$elemMatch": { "tags.id": args.newTagInfo._id } ; Before it had { "$elemMatch": { "tags.id": 1 } . May be that's the error.

Comment: I had already noticed that and modified my query accordingly. But the problem is not in that part to begin with, since my original `.updateMany({ 'posts.tags._id': args.newTagInfo._id },` is also able to look up the right documents. It's the `$set` expression that I'm not able to make work. Like I said, your solution throws no error, but doesn't update anything in the collection either.

Comment: What version of Mongo DB are you using? I did it with Mongo 4 and if you are using the Mongo DB 4, then try this code in Mongo console.

Comment: Am using Mongo Atlas which runs version 4.0.6.